# Ткните нуба в литературу: написание сегментированной e-mail рассылки с нуля

Tags: email, php, mysql

Ситуация:

- сайт, написанный от руки (никаких движков не задействовано)
- имеется клиентская база (100.000 + адресов).

Нужно реализовать сегментированную e-mail рассылку:

- сегментация путём анкетирования при подписке (проставление галочек на интересующие темы)
- рассылка писем на тему Х тем, кто проставил галочку на эту тему.

Будет создаваться новая БД с новой структурой, имеющихся подписчиков "заставят" проставить галочки, после чего они уже с проставленными галочками заносятся в новую БД.

Ткните, пожалуйста, в литературу, где можно почитать о написании e-mail рассылок с нуля, без использования движков (как написать самую простую рассылку, как лучше организовать структуру новой БД с сегментацией, как сделать, чтобы рассылка работала на 100.000+ адресов без перебоев, как не попасть в блеклисты("спамер!!!1")).

Гугл почти не выдаёт инфы (везде пишут из разряда "сегментируйте вашу рассылку, это хорошо!", конкретного кода и структуры не могу найти).

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы хотите очень много от Хэшкода, на ваш вопрос нельзя ответить кратко. Единственное, чем мог бы помочь - это конкретно ответить на вопрос "как организовать простенькую рассылку", в качестве примера прилагаю живой код из одной он-лайн игры:

```
   $from = 'support@example.com';
   $subject ='[example.com] - свежие новости игры';
   $aSpamList = $oDB->getAll("SELECT user_id, user_email FROM t_user_mailbase WHERE unsub = 0");
   for($i = 0; $i < count($aSpamList); $i++){

    $to = $aSpamList[$i]['user_email']; 
    $message = "Приветствуем!\r\n\r\nВы давненько не заходили в нашу игру, а у нас много интересных нововведений!\r\nНапример, .....\n-----\r\nС уважением, Администрация.\r\n\r\n--------\r\nЕсли вы не хотите в дальнейшем получать новости от игры,\r\nнажмите на эту ссылку: http://example.com/unsubscrible/?mail=".$to;

    $connect = fsockopen ('localhost', 25, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if(!$connect){
        echo $errstr."(".$errno.")<br>\n";
    } else {
        fputs($connect, "HELO localhost\r\n");
        fputs($connect, "MAIL FROM: $from\n");
        fputs($connect, "RCPT TO: $to\n");
        fputs($connect, "DATA\r\n");                              
        fputs($connect, "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        fputs($connect, "MIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n");
        fputs($connect, "To: $to\n");                                
        fputs($connect, "Subject: =?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($subject)."?=\n");  
        fputs($connect, $message." \r\n");
        fputs($connect, ".\r\n");
        fputs($connect, "RSET\r\n"); 
     }
     fclose($connect);                                
     $oDB->query("UPDATE t_user_mailbase SET last_send ='".date("G:i:s d-m-Y")."' WHERE user_id = ".$aSpamList[$i]['user_id']);
}
```

Предполагается, что у вас уже есть сервер с настроенным sendmail на 25-м порту и реальным ай-пи, к которому привязан домен, от имени которого вы шлете письмо.
Письма желательно оформлять в plain-text и обязательно предусматривать возможность отписки. 
Слать письма порциями, по 500-1000 штук в 10-15 минут.

Comment: @deivan, есть функция mail, которая предполагает избегание геморроя с реализацией smtp вручную. Если сервера разнесены, то как минимум это надо оборачивать или юзать какой-нибудь PHPMailer.

Comment: Хотя вроде и через php.ini можно задать сервак

Comment: здесь хороший повод новичку посмотреть как это работает по-настоящему. майл - удел домохозяек :)

Comment: @deivan, по-настоящему разработчик по-минимуму погрязает в геморрое, который может заставить тратить время на его поддержку.